# Check time interval from database with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, datetime

I have a database called `booking_system` which has a table named `bookings` with the following structure:

```
+--+--------+----+----------+----------+----------+
|id|username|room|book_date |time_since|time_until|
+--+--------+----+----------+----------+----------+
|1 |mari80u6|3   |2013-11-17|09:00:00  |11:00:00  |
+--+--------+----+----------+----------+----------+
```

The data is inserted into the database using PHP (no issue there). The problem is that now, based on the book_date, time_since and time_until information from the database, i need to check 
`$current_date` which is equal to `date('Y-m-d', strtotime('now'))` 
against the book_date column from the database in the first place. Secondly I want to check `$current_hour` which is equal to `date('H:i:s')` 
if it is between the interval of time_since & time_until columns. Finally if

```
mysql_num_rows == 0
```

the `src` attribute of an image should change to green

```
<img id="room3" src="css/images/3Green.png">
```

meaning that the room is available for booking otherwise it should look be red

```
<img id="room3" src="css/images/3Red.png">
```

I really don't know how to properly write the sql query being stuck at this:

```
$sql="SELECT id FROM bookings WHERE room='3' AND time_since < '$current_hour' < time_until";
```

Also if there are other prefered methods to achieve what I am looking for please let me know, I really appreciate any help I can get and I hope I made myself clear enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`value` < `value` < `value` is not a valid syntax. You need to use `AND` with multiple comparisions instead:

```
SELECT id 
FROM bookings 
WHERE room='3' 
AND time_since < '$current_hour' 
AND '$current_hour' < time_until";
```

Or use [**`BETWEEN`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between):

```
SELECT id 
FROM bookings 
WHERE room='3' 
AND '$current_hour' BETWEEN time_since AND time_until";
```